# React Native Axios not accepting server key

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I have a const below but somehow I get an error saying the server key was not sent along the request. I tried testing the API with PostMan and it works perfectly (application/json).

```
const AuthLogin = async (username, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${LOGIN}`,
            {
                username,
                password,
                server_key: SERVER_KEY,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        );
        let userInfo = response.data;
        console.log(userInfo);
        setUserInfo(userInfo);
        await saveUserInfo(userInfo);
        setIsLoading(false);
        return userInfo;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`login error ${e}`);
        setIsLoading(false);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

I tried adding the server_key as a header: Authorization: `Bearer ${SERVER_KEY}` and on the API URL: ${LOGIN}?server_key=${SERVER_KEY} still the same error.

Comment: Share a successful Postman request.

Comment: Response of a successful Postman request

{
    "api_status": 200,
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "access_token": "c7044fd00e56b54206358472dhgf8ff6d347b519973b0453ref1645fa32c480b48e0c6a062654100efe34c4e2190e97d1abc625902822b13",
    "user_id": "2684"
}

Comment: Response of a failed React Native request

{"api_status": "404", "errors": {"error_id": "1", "error_text": "Error: 404 POST (server_key) not specified"}}

Comment: You're giving the response - the request is what's needed here. Try logging out all of your variables in RN and make sure they match your Postman request.

Comment: On Postman I'm sending server_key, username, and password on the body (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). I tried switching application/json with application/x-www-form-urlencoded on RN still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to serialize data, something like this

```
import qs from 'qs';

const data = { 'bar': 123 };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

It seems that automatic serialization is not working, see the [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362).

Comment: Worked like a charm, I think the issues you mentioned with axios on github needs to be reopened and worked on. This is how my final const looks like

const data = qs.stringify({
                username,
                password,
                server_key: SERVER_KEY,
            });
            const response = await axios.post(
                `${LOGIN}`,
                data,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                }
            );